# Why it works when I assign the object with others' object?

Tags: c++, object, variable-assignment

I'd like to assign the object of type B to object of type A, but i don't know why it works with different types for the assignment?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        printf("B default constructor.\n");
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        printf("A Default constructor.\n");
    }

    A(B const& b) // if add the tag "explicit" for the constructor, it will not work...
    {
        printf("User constructor.\n");
    }

    A(const A& a)
    {
        printf("copy-constructor.\n");
    }

    void get(){printf("A::get\n");}
};

int main()
{
    A a = B(); // What's the meaning to assign object of type B to object of type A?
```

**Why it works with above line?**
**How it works when do this?**

```
    a.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every constructor that can be called with a single argument defines an implicit conversion **to** a class type. So the constructor:

```
A(B const& b)
```

is a conversion constructor. If this type of conversion is not useful, you've found the answer: declaring it as `explicit` can prevent it:

```
explicit A(B const& b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from thinking it is assignment. But `A a = B();` is initialization. `a` is not first created with default constructor and then assigned to, it is directly constructed. And while I don't have the standard reference handy, if you don't have the constructor but have the assignment operator overload, that line will not compile, because it is not assignemnt, it needs the right constructor. To have assignment, try

```
A a; 
a = B(); // actually assigns A(B()) implicitly if no operator= overload
```

If all data members of a class can be assigned, then objects of the class can be assigned, so that's why `a = A();` works without adding any code.

If you want to block the implicit conversion, make the constructor `explicit` (example in the other answer).